# Insert Calendar time into TextBox

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I inserted TextView into an activity and I want it to change according to time. As you can see in the code below the timeNow is supposed to get the current time from calendar and then variable time is supposed to get AM_PM from timeNow. Then I want my TextView to change into the current time. However when I load this activity the app crashes. What could be wrong? I simply want to change the TextView to current time (for example: 10:32AM) AM doesn't have to be there, it's good as long 10:32 is there. I'm completely new to android and java programming so a good explanation would be most appreciated.

```
Calendar timeNow = Calendar.getInstance();
int time = timeNow.get(Calendar.AM_PM);     
final TextView nextCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
nextCourse.setText(time);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do : `nextCourse.setText(String.valueOf(time));`

Since time is an `int`, it will try to apply the method `setText(int resid)` on your `textView`, which will throws a `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Still had a problem at first but I got it now

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.valueOf()` method to convert the time to a String before setting it on the `TextView`.

```
nextCourse.setText(String.valueOf(time));
```

According to your code what you are doing now is setting an `int` which makes the app to look for a resource with the specified integer. As the app cannot find a resource, the app crashes.